# Codeigniter HMVC : Error on running controllers having same name from different module name

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-2, hmvc

I'm using Codeigniter 2.1.3 with HMVC (https://bitbucket.org/wiredesignz/codeigniter-modular-extensions-hmvc/overview)

I've tried to run two modules in a view as shown below

```
<?php 
echo Modules::run('contact/mosite/contactform');  
echo Modules::run('social/mosite/facebook');  
?>
```

First module is running well, but second got failed to run.

If I run only second module, it will works fine.

I think the issue is on the **controller name**, both controller have same name.

How to fix this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, if this is because of same name (I'm not sure) then I think you can use `namespace` and to do this you can use this [patch](http://ellislab.com/forums/viewthread/212661/) to allow `namespacing` in `CodeIgniter`. I didn't use/test it but it works fine as other claimed.

**Important :** This patch replaces the core `Codeigniter.php` file so be aware of that.

Comment: It is better to save controllers/models/views with a prefix as module name.